# How to trigger a watch when I click my button?

Tags: angularjs

How can I do a `$watch()` on a button and trigger my `$watch()` when i press this button...?

HTML:

```
<button  style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                    Re-init tableau
                </button>
```

JS:

```
scope.$watch('[]', function () {}, true);
```

Comment: Why not just use the ng-click directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an `ngClick` on the button:

```
<button ng-click="addWatch()" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                    Re-init tableau
</button>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.addWatch = function(){
    if( !$scope.isWatchAdded ) {
      $scope.$watch('[]', function () {}, true);    
      $scope.isWatchAdded = true;
    }
}
```

This will add just once the `watch` expression

Comment: what is isWatchAdded is this any predefined function